# How to use just one sql statement to create a view to reach this goal?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

Here is a table1:

```
+--------------------+
| type | size | code |
+--------------------+
|   A  |  10  |   1  |
|   A  |   8  |   0  |
|   B  |   3  |   1  |
|   B  |   5  |   0  |
|   A  |   9  |   1  |
+--------------------+
```

Now I want to create a view to reach these goals:

`1. Group by "type" column`

`2. calculate avg(size) for each "type"`

`3. calculate the percent of "1" in "code" cloumn for "type"`

```
+----------------------------+
| type | avg(size) | percent |
+----------------------------+
|   A  |     9     |   2/3   |
|   B  |     4     |   1/2   |
+----------------------------+
```

What is the best way to create the view like this?

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL _and_ SQL Server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one,

```
CREATE VIEW viewName 
AS
SELECT `type`, 
       AVG(`size`),
       CONCAT(
              SUM(`code`), 
              '/',
              COUNT(`code`)
             ) percent
FROM table1
GROUP BY `type`
```

## [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a788/1)

Comment: @JasonHermann I know, that's why I added `for mysql`. see the tag.

Comment: @Coaku sure, try the answer above.

Comment: @Coaku I'm try to figure out why you `A` has an avg of `7`. Is it a typographic error? becuase in my calculation it should be `9`.

Comment: @Sami because `AS` is optional. :D

Comment: sorry, it's my fault...by the way , your answer is perfect :)

Comment: Thanks. After 3 years of using sql I came to know it today :(

Comment: @Sami it's not a problem if you usually use `AS`, actually it helps you determined that it has an `alias`.

Comment: Ok Thanks. One thing, i think you can use `SUM('code')` instead of `SUM(CASE WHEN 'code' = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` to make its look more easy

Comment: @Sami yeah you're right. i overlooked it because of `count`. hehe

Comment: @JohnWoo Sorry if i am cheating. As I have seen you great in sql queries. You may also have some deep touch with privileges and information_schema too. So have a look here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553132/how-to-use-just-one-sql-statement-to-create-a-view-to-reach-this-goal/12553151#12553151 whenever your are free :)

Answer (score 1):

```
create view myview as
select 
    type,
    avg(size) as avg_size,
    concat(sum(code), '/', count(code)) as percent
from t1
group by type
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that CODE is a numeric value:

```
select   
   t1.A as TYPE,   
   avg(SIZE) as AVGSIZE,   
   100 * sum(t1.CODE) / count(*) as PERCENT  
from TABLE1 as t1  
group by T1.TYPE;
```

If CODE is not numeric it might need to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

If `code` is numeric, and you're looking for the percentage as a floating-point number rather than as a human-readable fraction, then you can use

```
SELECT type, AVG(size) AS avgsize, AVG(code) AS percent
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY type
```